# Express.js - prepend sub-route to all defined routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nuxt.js

Let's say I have an Express app defined in a file, say `server.js` like this:

```js
const app = express();

app.use('/foo', foo);
app.use('/bar', bar);

module.exports = app;
```

I import this Express app in another file, say `index.js`:

```js
const app = require('./server');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const listen = (port) => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Backend listening on port ${port}!`);
    });
};

listen(port);
```

Now, the routes that are available for this app are `/foo` and `/bar`.

Is there a way to edit configuration in the `index.js` file so that the routes become `/api/foo` and `/api/bar`? Without touching `server.js` file.

## Use case:

I have a `Nuxt.js` app with a backend that is loaded into the `Nuxt` app via `serverMiddleware` property in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```js
serverMiddleware: [
    ...
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/server.js' },
],
```

This has the effect similar to what I described above: it imports the express app from `server.js` app and prepends all its routes with `/api`.

However, often I don't want to develop the frontend part of the `Nuxt` app, I just want to do changes on the backend. For this purpose I have a helper file like `index.js` above, which runs backend only. (Frontend often takes long time to compile, that's why I don't want to compile it when I don't need to.)

This creates a problem that all the routes are slightly different - they lack the `/api` at the beginning. The routes are being used in different tools like Postman etc. and suddenly they wouldn't work.

My current solution is to define `index.js` file in the same way as `server.js` file with all routes defined like I want them - instead of `app.use('/foo', foo);` there's `app.use('/api/foo', foo);` etc. but this has its own problems, e.g. if I change `server.js` I have to change `index.js`. I am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Not completely without changing server. In server you need to create a route, and in index to create the app and do app.use('/api', route).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the express 4.0 docs https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use you can use an `application` instance the same as you would a `router`. In short, just use the export of your `server.js` as a middleware at the route in which you want to insert it, as opposed to directly calling `.listen()` on it.

Here is some demo code that worked for me:

```
const express = require('express');
const app_inner = express();
app_inner.use('/foo', (req,res) => res.send('foo'));

const app_outer = express();
app_outer.use('/foo2', app_inner);

app_outer.listen(9999);
// web browser at localhost:9999/foo2/foo returns 'foo' as expected
```